I can`t get the Mesh Deform Modifier To work
I'm currently working on a project for a university. I use the Mesh Deform Modifier to simulate some kind of car destruction. I can see the changes in a viewport, but when I try to render an image it never shows.

↑Viewport shading image.

Rendered image, as you can see, some parts of a car (such as doors, hood, etc.) are actually affected by Mesh Deform Modifier, but not the car body.
To simplify.

↑ Red Car Body modifiers

↑ Red Car Deform Body modifiers

↑ Blue Car Body modifiers

↑ BlueCar Deform Body modifiers


↑ Black and blue car that deforms the way I want it to.
I've tried a ton of options, read a lot of similar topics, but I haven't found a solution yet.
